# Extract text and ignore next node

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

From this:

```
<span class="postbody">
    <span style="color: #8e2fb6">
        <span style="font-weight: bold">nickname</span>
    </span>     
    <br>
    Example text 
    <br>
    Example text
    <br>    
    <p class="signature">THIS IS WHAT I DO NOT WANT</p>
</span>
```

I want to extract:

```
<br>
Example text 
<br>
Example text
<br>
```

I tried: `span/text()[1]` but it seems not to work. I always get unwanted `p` class. Is it even possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to load your Html string into a HtmlDocument or HtmlNode (Using .load() function).

ChildNodes collection contains every children of your current node (Basically every nodes under **span.postbody**).

After that what you need to do is pretty obvious, just grab **#text** and **br** nodes (keep in mind that you will receive some **#text** nodes that have just whitespace characters. You may want to filter it out in the result.

```
//load html to HtmlNode
node.ChildNodes.Where(n => n.Name.Equals("#text") || n.Name.Equals("br")) //It will return collection of HtmlNode
```

Comment: Adding some explanation would help make this answer better.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to add some explanation but it's kind of obvious. Anyway, I will explain it a little bit in my edit

Comment: Even "obvious" answers can benefit from explanations. Yours showed up in the low quality posts queue because it was just a line of code with nothing else. The edit is a good improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery selector for postbody, then the .text method which should ignore the HTML. This will also ignore the 
.

$('.postbody').text();

An alternative would be to iterate through the children of the $('.postbody').text();

Answer (score 0):

```
'//text()[preceding-sibling::br and normalize-space()]'
```